# How to get Nhibernate to break the physical connection to the database?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, database-connection

I'm connect to database using Nhibernate

```
_sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
_sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
_session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession(new DbInterceptor());
_sessionForSequenceQuery = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
_sequenceQuery = _sessionForSequenceQuery.CreateSQLQuery("select nextval('sequence')");
```

when I need to disconnect from the database, I do

```
_sessionForSequenceQuery.Disconnect();
_session.Disconnect();
_sessionFactory.Dispose();
```

But the physical connection to the database remains. As I understand it breaks the physical connection is Nhibernate when it deems it necessary. How do I get him to do so immediately?

Comment: Have you tried setting the [connection release mode](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#transactions-connection-release) property to "on_close". Please note the documentation says "its use is highly discouraged".

Comment: It's not NHibernate, but ADO.NET's connection pooling.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that for _session you should invoke Close, not a Disconnect:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-endingsession-close

> The main implication of Close() is that the ADO.NET connection will be relinquished by the session.

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-disconnection

> The method ISession.Disconnect() will disconnect the session from the ADO.NET connection and return the connection to the pool (unless you provided the connection).

Comment: ok, then probably NHibernate manages all connections to SQL Server, and when you do Close / Disconnect it just put the connections back to Connection Pool. Probably you can try to change this behavior somewhere in nhibernate configuration, but I think this can add some performance issues to your code.